# 2D array - sorting | Access violation reading location error | In C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Hey guys I am trying to finish my code but instead of getting values i am getting an error msg
.when i am about to enter lien number  54 or 60.

```
if(*arr[rows*columns]<num) or printf("Number value %d in a two-dimensional size is:%d\n",num,*arr[num]);
```

This is error msg.

`Unhandled exception at 0x013137b2 in LB_12.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xabababab`.

Mission description and the error msg int he next picture.
what is wrong? i have to create another array and copy the values if i want the program to print the values?

[image: Mission discrption and error msg]

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void SortArray(int **arr,int rows,int columns,int num);
void freemalloc ( int **arr,int rows);

void main()
{
    int **arr;
    int i,j,rows,columns,num;
    printf("Please enter the size of 2D array(rows ,cols)");
    scanf("%d %d",&rows , &columns);
    arr=(int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int *)); // Allocate array of pointers
    if(!arr) // Terms - if there is not enough memory,print error msg and exit the program.
        {
            printf("alloc failed\n");
            return ;
        }
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        arr[i]=(int *)malloc(columns*sizeof(int)); // Allocate memory for each row
    printf("Please fill the 2D array\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
        {
            for (j=0 ; j<columns ; j++)
            {
                printf("row:%d columns:%d\n", i,j);
                scanf("%d" , &arr[i][j]);
            }
        }

    printf("Please enter a postive number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    SortArray(arr,rows,columns,num);
    freemalloc(arr,rows);

system("pause");
return;
}
void SortArray(int **arr,int rows,int columns,int num)
{
    int i,j,temp; 
    for(i=0 ; i<rows ; i++ ) // Bubble sort for sorting the 2d array
        {
            for(j=0 ; j<i-1 ; j++ )
            {
                if(arr[i][j]>arr[i][j+1])
                {
                    temp=arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j]=arr[i][j+1];
                    arr[i][j+1]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    if(*arr[rows*columns]<num)
        {
            printf("No solution,The maximum value is:%d\n",arr[rows*columns]);
        }
    else
    {
        printf("Number value %d in a two-dimensional size is:%d\n",num,*arr[num]);
    }
}
void freemalloc ( int **arr,int rows)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i<rows ; i++) // Loop for free the array of pointers
    {
            free(arr[i]); // free each seprate row
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: To better understand the problem, you need to run your program in the debugger. Then when the crash happens it will stop at the location of the crash, and you will be able to examine and walk the call stack as well as examine values of variables and expressions.

Comment: I did.I told you in the post in lines if(*arr[rows*columns]<num) or printf("Number value %d in a two-dimensional size is:%d\n",num,*arr[num]); i got the crash

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `rows * columns` is larger than what you have allocated, meaning you try to dereference a random pointer, leading to *undefined behavior* and causing the crash.

Also, you will never sort anything, as the outer loop condition is always false (try changing `>` to `<`).

Comment: So i change this line for(i=0 ; i<rows ; i++ ) and in the memory allocate is change to rows*columns and i still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is :

```
printf("Number value %d in a two-dimensional size is:%d\n",num,*arr[num]);
```

You're asking for some number and put it in variable num. What makes you think that number num is first number in num-th row?

There might be, and propably are more problems with this code.
EDIT:
`*arr[num]` is evaluated from right to left. `[]` have higher precedence than `*` operator.
So it first `does arr[num]`. and result of that is dereferenced `*(arr[num])`. num is treated like a row, so if you don't have enough rows-you got memory violation because you are beyond array

Comment: So how should it be like? if i entered this num is 3 so it's supposed to give me the third largest number in the array no?

Comment: num is the number that we get from the user.Value of NUM number should display the value NUM system size.SO after i sorted the array if i write arr [num] is should give me the vaule of the third number in the array. if i entred 3.

Comment: I seem to have a pretty big information gap I'm pretty new to the subject. Would love to have thicker tip or information material to read so that I can solve this exercise

Comment: Seems like you are missing basics of multidimensional arrays. Do this exercise without allocating memory on fixed size array. When you get it, then  it will be 5 minute task to change it. Also do it step by step. Check when making every change. If you tried to print your array before sorting and after you wouldn't end up with 100 lines of unpredictable code that noone, even you are willing to debug line by line.

Comment: I just print it and it's didn't even sort the array something is wrong about this line if(arr[i][j]>arr[i][j+1])